# How to disable access to a django APIs based on is_active boolean field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-class-based-views

I have an author's model with a field:

```
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I wish to restrict access to the author whose is_active=False.

I can use something like this in every api:

```
get_object_or_404(uuid=id, is_active=True)
```

But I wish to globally restrict access to the UUID whose is_active=false, instead of actually writing this statement in every api.

Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: Are there places where you __do__ want these authors to be returned? You could use a custom manager that excludes all non-active authors by default

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom permission class and use it as permission class,  where you will check if the user is authenticated and also an active member.

Something like this :

```
class UserIsActive(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_active:
            return True
        return False

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.user.is_active:
            return True
        return False
```

Comment: Note that this check would be redundant if using the default `ModelBackend` auth backend, as inactive users would by design not be able to authenticate. It would however be relevant if using `AllowAllUsersModelBackend` auth.